# Return Remaining Whole Text From Slice Method

Tags: javascript, string, function, slice

I want to remove the 'H' only from the 'Hello world, welcome to the universe.'. How can i return the whole text and just remove the 'H'. Here's my code below.

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
  var n = str.slice(0, 1) + str.slice(0, 5);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using substring without the second argument.  This starts at the second character and continues to the end of the string.

```
str.substring(1);
```

You can also use `slice(1)`, and that will also return a new string, but using `substring` makes it clearer you are actually starting with a string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two `slice` statements - remove the second one to extract only the first character:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
  var n = str.slice(0, 1);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show "H"</button>
```

You could also use `str[0]`:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
  var n = str[0];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show "H"</button>
```